# How to resolve the conflict between the require methods of node.js and monaco-editor.loader

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, monaco-editor

## Question Part

#### I want to use `monaco-editor` in Electron(ver. 13), and I used static file.

To require the `monaco-editor`, I puted

```html
<script src="../plugins/plugin-monaco/loader.js"></script>
```

part in the head of the page.
But I still use `nodeIntergration` to let the renderer process know the type of the system to  adjust the control buttons. So I required `'os'` by

```js
require('os')
```

, and from then on the contral pad says that:

```js
vue.min.js:6 Error: Check dependency list! Synchronous require cannot resolve module 'os'. This is the first mention of this module!
    at r.synchronousRequire (loader.js:8)
    at n (loader.js:9)
    at wn.data (index.html:90)
    at wn.<anonymous> (vue.min.js:6)
    at vue.min.js:6
    at vue.min.js:6
    at vn (vue.min.js:6)
    at wn.t._init (vue.min.js:6)
    at new wn (vue.min.js:6)
    at fn_createVue (index.html:86)
```

OK. It is insteresting, isn't it? I enbled the function `nodeIntergration`, but it says cannot find the moudle `'os'`!
When I try to put

```js
delete require
```

It says that:

```js
vue.min.js:6 ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at wn.data (index.html:90)
    at wn.<anonymous> (vue.min.js:6)
    at vue.min.js:6
    at vue.min.js:6
    at vn (vue.min.js:6)
    at wn.t._init (vue.min.js:6)
    at new wn (vue.min.js:6)
    at fn_createVue (index.html:86)
    at index.html:306
Ue @ vue.min.js:6
vue.min.js:6 ReferenceError: platform is not defined
    at wn.eval (eval at Ya (vue.min.js:6), <anonymous>:3:283)
    at wn.e._render (vue.min.js:6)
    at wn.r (vue.min.js:6)
    at fn.get (vue.min.js:6)
    at new fn (vue.min.js:6)
    at vue.min.js:6
    at wn.$mount (vue.min.js:6)
    at wn.$mount (vue.min.js:6)
    at wn.t._init (vue.min.js:6)
    at new wn (vue.min.js:6)
```

When I deleted the load of `loader.js` file, it says:

```js
index.html:305 Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at index.html:305
```

So **HOW CAN I SOLVE THE PROBLEM?**(Waiting online, very anxious)

---

## Additional Part:

### The way to require `monaco-editor`:

```html
<script src="../plugins/plugin-monaco/loader.js"></script>
```

```js
require.config({ paths: { 'vs': '../plugins/plugin-monaco' }})
require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], fn_createVue())
```

and the function `fn_createVue()` create a viewModel of `Vue.js`, including

```js
require('os')
```

---

## Versions Part

| moudle | version |
| --- | --- |
| Electron | 13.1.6 |
| monaco-editor | 0.25.2 |

Comment: electron is basically a browser with an "it looks like an app" wrapper, why would it need to run anything that contains `require('os')`? You can check that in its own main.cjs (or whatever you called it) and then forward it to the .html file you're loading in the mainWindow, using a query argument like `blah.html?os=....` - why would a page script need to run node-only code?

Comment: Thanks. this requestion is great, but if I do it as you say, how should I let the renderer process connect with main process by `ipc`?